# I have a website that is blocked by domain, but the cloudflare ip address is not blocked

Tags: ip, discord, cloudflare

The website https://discord.com/ is currently blocked in my country, I tried using vpns and such but it is too slow and a big mess after a while.

I realized that discord uses cloudflare, after getting the assigned cloudflare IP for discord, it was working, but that IP just returns `403 Forbidden`. That is when I realized that the restriction is only at domain level and the website can be accessed Somehow with this cloudflare IP.

My question is how can I get access to the discord domain using that cloudflare IP Address.

`https://162.159.136.232/`

ps: Discord is not geo-blocking the country, there is another internet provider that allows discord.

Comment: Have you tried using the desktop app (instead of the website) to see if it's not blocked (it might use different connections methods.)

Comment: If 'domain-level' blocking is done by blocking/altering DNS (which is not the only method), you could instead use /etc/hosts (slightly tedious), or a protected DNS like DNS-over-HTTPS DNS-over-TLS DNScrypt if supported by your browser (or perhaps a local stub?) (only if it is not _also_ blocked).

Answer (score 2):

**You can't**.

Coudflare isn't simply a data center that hosts servers and every IP goes to a specific website.

What Cloudflare does is having a ton of load balancers and edge proxies all over and based on the domain accessed it will serve up the resources for that website, but it's in no way this IP = this website (and also not this website = this IP.)